# How to create a plpgsql code block for sum and average of three numbers

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

To create a code block for sum and average of three numbers with sub functions in plpgsql language

Tired sum but can't able to create a sub function for average

Answer (score 0):

Why PL/pgSQL?

```
select sum(val), avg(val)
from (
  values (10),(20),(42)
) as t(val);
```